# How to use sed to copy file content to another at a specific line number

Tags: sed, file-io

Given 2 files with the following content

`File 1`

```
4
4
7
```

`File 2`

```
Hello
World
```

Using `sed` how can we insert `file2`'s content into `file1` starting from a specific line number (the second for example) to get

`OutFile`

```
4
4
Hello
World
7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed '2r file2 ' file1`

---

**Breakdown**

sed command syntax is `[addr]command[options]`

`2`: line number address
`r`: read from file command
`file2`: file we read from

`file1`: is the one to be operated on

Follow this [section](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-script-overview)